# Как работать с svg иконками в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, create-react-app

Сейчас просто вставляю несколько иконок в файл Icons.js, и импортирую уже где необходимо.
Вот пример иконки:

```
class IconPlus extends React.Component {
        static defaultProps = {
            width: '7',
            height: '7',
            stroke: '#d5d5d5',
            fill: '#000'
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <svg className="icon-plus" width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} fill={this.props.fill}
                     stroke={this.props.stroke} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6.93 6.93">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" strokeWidth="1.1" d="M3.47.55v5.83M6.38 3.47H.55"/>
                </svg>
            )
        }
    }
```

И появляются всякие неудобства: ошибки что атрибут stroke-linecap должен быть strokeLinecap и т.п. Как автоматизировать и сделать удобнее?

Comment: Создай компонент Icon и в зависимости от пропса, например, name отдавай нужную иконку. Это один из вариантов. Ещё можно тупо импортировать нужную иконку как обычно это делается с пакетами (через file-loader). Можно еще поискать готовые npm пакеты иконок если не хочется изобретать велосипед.

Comment: А какое автоматизированное решение посоветуете, чтобы переводить атрибуты в реакт наименования, например из stroke-width в strokeWidth, а то в консоли после добавления иконки появляются ошибки, связанные с наименованиями

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите смешивать SVG и JSX, то вам нужно некоторые аттрибуты переписать, как вы уже заметили.

Как этого не делать - вариантов несколько

1. Уберите `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` и просто вставляйте собранную строку

   ```
   render: function() {
       return (
           <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120">
               <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/>
           </svg>
       );
   }
   ```
2. Вариант отправить рекат в пешее эротическое путешествие с его проверками:

   ```
   render: function() {
      return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "<svg>...</svg>"}} />;
   }
   ```
3. Хранить картинки отдельно, импортировать как модули и стилизовать их через css.